# Creating a binary tree from a parenthesized string

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, parsing, binary-tree

How would I go about using a parenthesized string to create a binary tree?
Would a possible solution also make use of a stack in some way?

Example: the string: `"(A(B)(C))"` should create a tree that looks like the following:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

Something else to note is that `()` would be used to denote that a node would not have a child at that position. To further illustrate, `"(A()(B))"`,
denotes that the node "A" would have no left child but would have a right child, named "B".

Comment: Do you assume 3rd row? if yes draw it -  A(B(E)(F))(C(G)(H)). Because imo it would be harder to draw it than calculate what to draw in a console environment

Comment: How is your initial string valid if `B` and `C` are supposed to be `Node` types? If `()` is used to denote no child, then shouldn't it be `"(A(B()())(C()()))"` (to fully represent the `Left` and `Right` nodes of `B` and `C`)? Can you please provide a more detailed example of a valid tree string?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input string is well-formed, you can indeed use stacks to build a tree structure. I used a stack of flags which runs alongside a stack of parent nodes to keep track of whether a left child for each parent has been handled (either left empty or assigned a child). This flag stack is also modified for empty parenthesis signifying an empty child.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        string[] tests = {
            "()",
            "(A(B(C)))",
            "(A(B()))",
            "(A()(B))",
            "(A()(B()))",
            "(A()(B()()))",
            "(A()(B(C)))",
            "(A()(B()(C)))",
            "(A(B(E)(F))(C(G)(H()(I))))",
        };

        foreach (string test in tests)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test + "\n");
            PrintTree(ParseTree(test));
            Console.WriteLine(new String('_', 26) + "\n");
        }
    }

    static Node ParseTree(string str) 
    {
        var parent = new Stack<Node>();
        var hasLeft = new Stack<bool>();
        Node root = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (str[i] == '(') 
            {
                if (str[++i] == ')') // "()" substring
                {
                    if (hasLeft.Count == 0) 
                    {
                        return null; // empty tree
                    }

                    // mark left child as handled for this node
                    hasLeft.Pop();
                    hasLeft.Push(true); 
                }
                else // str[i] is a node; connect it to its parent
                {
                    var node = new Node(str[i]);

                    if (parent.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (hasLeft.Peek()) 
                        {
                            parent.Peek().right = node;
                        }
                        else // left child hasn't been handled yet
                        {
                            parent.Peek().left = node;
                            hasLeft.Pop();
                            hasLeft.Push(true);
                        }
                    }
                    else // no parent found; make this the root
                    {
                        root = node;
                    }

                    parent.Push(node);
                    hasLeft.Push(false);
                }
            }
            else if (str[i] == ')') 
            {
                parent.Pop();
                hasLeft.Pop();
            }
        }

        return root;
    }

    static void PrintTree(Node root, int depth = 0)
    {
        if (root != null) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new String(' ', depth) + root.val);

            if (root.left != null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new String(' ', depth) +  " ──L─┐");
                PrintTree(root.left, depth + 6);
            }
                
            if (root.right != null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new String(' ', depth) +  " ──R─┐");
                PrintTree(root.right, depth + 6);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Node 
{
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public char val;

    public Node(char val) 
    {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

Partial output:

```
(A()(B(C)))

A
 ──R─┐
      B
       ──L─┐
            C
__________________________

(A()(B()(C)))

A
 ──R─┐
      B
       ──R─┐
            C
__________________________

(A(B(E)(F))(C(G)(H()(I))))

A
 ──L─┐
      B
       ──L─┐
            E
       ──R─┐
            F
 ──R─┐
      C
       ──L─┐
            G
       ──R─┐
            H
             ──R─┐
                  I
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create a static `Parse` method on the `Node` class that returns a `Node` based on an input string. The logic would be something like:

1. Remove the outer parenthesis
2. Remove and assign the Name to a new Node
3. Determine the string that represents the Left node (this can be done by counting opening and closing parenthesis until the count of each is equal).
4. Assign the Left node to the result of `Node.Parse` using the "Left" string
5. Assign the Right node to the result of `Node.Parse` using the "Right" string

I also added some code to print out the tree in a sort of rudimentary way, so you can see what the values of each node looks like.

For example the `Node` class below implements a `Parse` method that will create nodes based on your string input:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Node Left { get; set; }
    public Node Right { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Node based on a valid input string: "(Name(Left)(Right))", 
    /// where 'Left' and 'Right' are empty or valid strings like above.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">Input string to parse</param>
    /// <returns>Root node of the tree</returns>
    public static Node Parse(string input)
    {
        input = input?.Trim();

        // Some light validation
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || input == "()") return null;

        if (input.Length < 7)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                $"input '{input}' is not long enough to represent a valid " +
                "node. The minimum string length is 7 characters: (A()())");
        }

        if (!input.StartsWith("(") || !input.EndsWith(")"))
        {
            throw new FormatException(
                $"input '{input}' must be surrounded by parenthesis");
        }

        // Remove outer parenthesis so input is now: "Name(Left)(Right)"
        input = input.Substring(1, input.Length - 2);

        // Find the name and start of left node
        var leftNodeStart = input.IndexOf('(', 1);
        var root = new Node {Name = input.Substring(0, leftNodeStart)};

        // Remove name so input is now just: "(Left)(Right)"
        input = input.Substring(leftNodeStart);

        // Find the end of the left node by counting opening and closing parenthesis
        // When the opening count is equal to the closing count, we have our Left set
        var openParenthesisCount = 0;
        var closeParenthesisCount = 0;
        var leftNodeLength = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] == '(') openParenthesisCount++;
            else if (input[i] == ')') closeParenthesisCount++;

            if (openParenthesisCount == closeParenthesisCount)
            {
                leftNodeLength = i + 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Recursive calls to create Left and Right children
        root.Left = Node.Parse(input.Substring(0, leftNodeLength));
        root.Right = Node.Parse(input.Substring(leftNodeLength));

        return root;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        PrintTree();
    }        

    private static class Connector
    {
        public const string Empty = "  ";
        public const string Single = "╚═";
        public const string Double = "╠═";
        public const string Extension = "║";
    }

    private static class Position
    {
        public const string Empty = "";
        public const string Left = "Left : ";
        public const string Right = "Right: ";
    }

    private void PrintTree(string indent = "", string position = Position.Empty,
        bool extendParentConnector = false, string connector = Connector.Empty)
    {
        // Extend the parent's connector if necessary by
        // adding a "║" under the parent node's connector
        if (extendParentConnector && indent.Length > position.Length + 2)
        {
            var replaceIndex = indent.Length - position.Length - 2;
            indent = indent.Remove(replaceIndex, 1)
                .Insert(replaceIndex, Connector.Extension);
        }
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
        Console.Write(indent + connector);

        Console.ForegroundColor = position == Position.Left
            ? ConsoleColor.DarkCyan
            : ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;

        Console.Write(position);
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
        Console.WriteLine($" {Name} ");
        Console.ResetColor();

        var nextIndent = indent + new string(' ', position.Length + 2);
        var extendParent = connector == Connector.Double;

        Left?.PrintTree(nextIndent, Position.Left, extendParent,
            Right == null ? Connector.Single : Connector.Double);

        Right?.PrintTree(nextIndent, Position.Right, extendParent, Connector.Single);
    }
}
```

In use, this would look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var nodeString = "(A(B(C(L()())(M()()))(D()()))(E(F(G(H()())())(I()(J()())))(K()())))";

    var rootNode = Node.Parse(nodeString);

    rootNode.Print();

    Console.Write("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And the output looks like:

[image: ![![enter image description here]